# Get DB Record Update notification with HTML SSE

Tags: javascript, php, html, event-listener, server-sent-events

I would like to allow a user via browser to receive updates if a database record has been changed in (near) real time without reloading the web page.

The idea is:

- User opens url /dbrecord.php?id=12345
- Registers for SSE (or something else) to receive updates to the record
- Received on screen notification of what has been changed in the record without reloading the page

However this needs to be performant as there are a lot of DB Change events and a lot of potential users. Can you please let me know if the approach is good or are there better technologies / approaches to build something like this?

UPDATE: Found this - [Server Side Events with PHP & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568180/server-side-events-with-php-mysql) But it requires a while(true) loop in the PHP script and this cannot be good to have the SQL Query in there?! Any feedback?

Thanks,
fj

Comment: using a while loop is fine and querying inbetween iterations is fine (you need to query your data somehow).  a better sse example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081040/661872

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies it for me. Appreciate your support!